# checking if a database exists

Tags: php, mysql

The code below works fine except it throws a warning when connecting to a database that does not exist. This works fine in product where errors are off, but I would rather not have errors if I don't need to.

```
function cpanel_db_connect($dbname) {
    // normalize
    $dbname = convert_to_slug($dbname);
    $dbname = CPANEL_USER . '_' . $dbname;

    $dbuser = CPANEL_USER . '_' . CPANEL_DB_USER;

    // connnect database
    $mysqli = new mysqli(CPANEL_DB_HOST, $dbuser, CPANEL_DB_PASS, $dbname);

    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        return false;
    }

    return $mysqli;
}
```

Comment: You might be able to simply suppress errors with the `@` operator, e.g. `$mysqli = @new mysqli(CPANEL_DB_HOST, $dbuser, CPANEL_DB_PASS, $dbname);`

Comment: Since you're using the OOP version of mysqli, just do a try/catch around the connect section.

Comment: What warning/error do you get?

Comment: @Marc, `MySQLi` doesn't throw an exception on connect. You have to check the error via `connect_error` on the returned object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mysqli = @new mysqli(CPANEL_DB_HOST, $dbuser, CPANEL_DB_PASS, $dbname);
```

The above works!

Comment: You may want to investigate using a dedicated login for this sort of thing, and querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database directly: `select SCHEMA_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA where SCHEMA_NAME='your db name here'` is better than trying to connect to the (potentially not there) database and checking for an error.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a good practice to suppress warnings/errors using the @ sign in PHP. You could accidentally suppress an invalid username or password message and you would never know it.

A more appropriate way of checking if the database exists is creating a new instance of Mysql or Mysqli (without specifying the default database) and executing the following query (similar to Marc B's comment):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `exists` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMATA.SCHEMA_NAME='my_database_name'
```

Then you can check the value of the key `exists` to see if the database is there or not.

Here's a sample code:

```php
// statement to execute
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `exists` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMATA.SCHEMA_NAME="my_database_name"';

// execute the statement
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

// extract the value
$row = $query->fetch_object();
$dbExists = (bool) $row->exists;
```

It is a bit longer but it's safer.

Answer (score 0):

This works, just replace $dbname in this code:

```
if (empty (mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES LIKE '$dbname' ")))){
echo "DB does Not exist"; }else{    echo "DB  exists!";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating to MYSQLI:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');
$dbname='test';
if (empty (mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW DATABASES LIKE '$dbname'")))) 
{
    echo "DB not exist<br>"; 
}
else
{
    echo "DB exist<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to connect to DB server without selecting a DB, and only connecting if DB exists:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_biz['server'], $db_biz['user'], $db_biz['password']);

$query = 'SHOW DATABASES LIKE "' . $db_biz['dbName'] . '"';
$resShowBizDB = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($resShowBizDB->num_rows == 1) { //Found database
    $mysqli->select_db($db_biz['dbName']);
    
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { //Check for errors
        var_dump($mysqli);
        echo "Failed to connect to biz database: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
} else { //Didn't find DB
    die('<h1>ERROR</h1><p>Found no database</p>');
}
```